# How can I create a Docker container whose timezone matches that of my local machine?

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, timezone, dockerfile

I'm using Docker 19.  I have the following Dockerfile.  Notice how I set the time zone to US EST ...

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
  
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install unzip -y

RUN apt-get install tzdata
ENV TZ=America/New_York
RUN ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
...
```

Is there any way I can author my file such that the time zone gets set to the local machine that it's running on?  I'm on Central time zone but have team mates in other time zones.  If it's useful, the above is part of a docker-compose file that looks roughly like this ...

```
version: "3.2"
services:

  sql-server-db:
    build: ./
    container_name: sql-server-db
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
```

Some of us are on Macs, but it's possible for folks to be on Windows or Ubuntu.  If it's easier you can consider that everyone is on Macs.

Answer (score 5):

using docker run command:

```
-e TZ=`ls -la /etc/localtime | cut -d/ -f8-9`
```

[Source](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2396#issuecomment-358150983)

if you still want to use volumes you need to share /etc form the Docker UI in your MAC "Prefernces --> Resources --> FILE SHARING"

**Update**

for docker-compose :

under build section use:

```
args:
  - TZ
```

and then:

```
environment:
    - TZ=${TZ}
```

and then start it like - after re-build -:

```
export TZ=`ls -la /etc/localtime | cut -d/ -f8-9` && docker-compose up -d --build
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm bringing up my container (or rather an extension I'm using) wiht "docker-compose up".  Is there any way to include the environment setting you mention above in a docker-compose.yml file or in the Dockerfile itself?

Comment: Thank you but you are still creating the environment variable outside the docker-compose build process.  Is there any way to move what you have out of an external variable and create it from within the docker-compose.yml file or the Dockerfile that it uses to build? (The pytest plugin I'm using simply calls "docker-compose up" and I don't have the ability to rewrite how it brings up the container)

Answer (score 1):

you can set the time zone whatever you want in your host machine then you can map your local time to the container through volume mapping. Like this,

```
volumes:
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
```

For mac the location of localtime could be different. You can mount that location through volume mapping.

Comment: I'm running Mac High Sierra and this results in a "The path /etc/localtime is not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker." error.

Comment: I don't work on a mac so won't be able to try but this might help you. https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2396

Answer (score 0):

If it's okay to use a script to do docker-compose jobs, I think a workaround could be to set current timezone inside a shell variable, and pass it as an environment variable to containers.

The script would be:

```
TIMEZONE=`cat /etc/timezone`
docker-compose up -d  # or whatever
```

And in docker-compose file, you use this variable:

```
web:
  environment:
    - TZ=${TIMEZONE}
```

Note: You don't need to do anything on build time to set timezone. You can pass a `TZ` environment variable to the container and the timezone of the container would be what you want.

P.S. I'm not familiar with Mac, so `/etc/timezone` would be in a different location, or maybe Mac provides this value inside a predefined environment variable itself.

Comment: I gave "TIMEZONE=`cat /etc/timezone`" a whirl on Mac, but got "cat: /etc/timezone: No such file or directory".

Comment: @Dave What about `/etc/localtime`? `cat` it and check if it contains the time zone string.

Comment: That was suggestd by @Bhargav11, but it resulted in an error.  I am able to run "date" in a terminal and see the timezone ("Fri Jul 31 07:53:10 CDT 2020").  Maybe I can use that somehow?